# I create a clone of a div on click. The limit is 6 clones. If I delete a clone it breaks the code that limits it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I have a large button on the left and a form on the right. When you click the button on the left it allows you to create 6 forms in total. That is the set limit and you can not go over it.

**Problem #1** - If you select the X icon to delete one of the clones. And then begin adding more clones again. It breaks the set clone limit 1-6 and allows you to create infinite clones.

**Problem #2** - How do i remove the X Icon from the first/initial form and only have it "allowed" on its clones.

Thanks!

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1943/)**

**JS**

```
var clones_limit = 5;
var cloned_nbr = $(".clonedInput").length-1; //Exclude Default (first) div 

function clone()
{
  if(cloned_nbr<clones_limit)
  {
    cloned_nbr++;

    var new_clone =  $(".clonedInput").first().clone();
    $("#formy").append(new_clone);
    rearrange();
  }
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    cloned_nbr--;
   rearrange();
}

function rearrange(){
var count = 1;
var totalCount = $(".clonedInput").length;
$(".clonedInput").each(function(){
$(this).attr("id", "clonedInput"+count).find(".label-nbr").text(count).end().
find(".category").attr("id","category"+count).end().find(".remove").toggle(totalCount!=1).attr("id","remove"+count).on("click", remove);
count++;
});
}
$(".clone").on("click", clone);

$(".remove").on("click", remove);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the way you were attaching `click event` for `.remove` element. since you were attaching it on create, it used to trigger `remove` for all the elements recreated and hence decreasing the count of `cloned_nbr` back to `0`. So just remove the `click` event attaching and make use of **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

**Faulty code**

```
function rearrange() {
  var count = 1;
  var totalCount = $(".clonedInput").length;
  $(".clonedInput").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "clonedInput" + count).find(".label-nbr").text(count).end()
    .find(".category").attr("id", "category" + count).end().find(".remove")
    .toggle(totalCount != 1).attr("id", "remove" + count).on("click", remove);
                                                       //^^^this was causing the issue
    count++;
  });
}
```

Below is the changes, you need to do.

**Updated Code**

```
function rearrange() {
  var count = 1;
  var totalCount = $(".clonedInput").length;
  $(".clonedInput").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "clonedInput" + count).find(".label-nbr").text(count).end()
    .find(".category").attr("id", "category" + count).end().find(".remove")
    .toggle(totalCount != 1).attr("id", "remove" + count);
                                                          //^^^No need to attach here
    count++;
  });
}

$(document).on("click", ".remove", remove);//Event delegation
```

## [`UPDATED FIDDLE HERE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tfFLt/1951/)

---

**UPDATE - 1**

For **Problem - 2** Just add below `CSS`

```
div[id^="clonedInput"]:first-child .remove{
  display:none;
}
```

## [`UPDATED FIDDLE 2`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tfFLt/1951/)

Comment: Works brilliantly! Do you have any solution for my "problem #2? If you do not create any additional clones and you hit the X on the initial form. It deletes it. And then you are unable to bring it back without a refresh. So I was wondering how to hide it for flavor profile #1

Thanks!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: btw your updated fiddle 2 link is wrong but the code snippet worked perfectly.

Comment: Oops.. I did not update the fiddle, but just executed the code.. Anyways, updated the link... Thank you.. :)

Comment: btw how did u make your links so big?

Comment: Added `h1`.. Just edit the answer.. You will see it.. :) But yea dont make any changes and save it.. :)